# Set Do Not Trade as default for New Contacts?

Tags: contacts

Is it possible to set Do Not Trade as the default for new contacts?

Our organization requires consent to trade, and some of the new contacts, entered by volunteers, did not specify Do Not Trade & it has caused some confusion. In order to prevent this in the future we'd like to have this as default.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) installed and then create a rule with a trigger of *Contact of any type is added* with an action of *Set Privacy Options of a Contact* = *Privacy option(s) Do not Trade switched ON*.